# Microsoft Teams Camera Shows Black Screen

Tags: ms-office, video, camera, microsoft

Having tried a Mac Mini and MacBook Pro, Microsoft Teams shows a black screen in the video preview during calls. Others on the video call see the same black screen.

This issue has manifested on the MacBook with built-in camera, and with a Mac Mini using an external Logitech C922 camera connected via USB.

On iPhone and iPad using the Teams app, the same user can make video calls perfectly.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be seen in Teams device settings.

[image: Microsoft Teams Devices Settings]

Make a test call. This gives us a big clue as it highlights the video camera is unavailable due to permissions.

Fix by enabling in System Preferences under Security & Privacy as follows.
[image: System Preferences Security & Privacy]